# Already value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@64fcf46a] for key bound to thread when making a request using webflux but not using JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-webflux

I am new to webflux and I am trying to create a controller using Mono. Problem is, when I try to return a Mono, I get the exception below.

> Already value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@64fcf46a] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@21708736] bound to thread [http-nio-8080-exec-2]

Here is the code snippet which causes the problem.

Controller

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
@Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@RequestMapping(ConsultaCNDRoutes.CONSULTA_CND_BASE_ROUTE)
public class ConsultaCNDRest extends RestControllerAuditedBase {

    private ConsultaCNDService consultaCNDService;
    
    @Autowired
    public ConsultaCNDRest(ConsultaCNDService consultaCNDService) {
        this.consultaCNDService = consultaCNDService;
    }
    
    @ApiOperation("Checa a disponibilizacao do servico")
    @GetMapping(value = ConsultaCNDRoutes.CONSULTA_CND_STATUS_ROUTE,
            produces = "application/json")
    public Mono<String> checarServicoConsultaCND() {
        try {
            Mono<String> status = consultaCNDService.consultarServicoCNDStatus();
            return status;
        } catch (CNDServicoNaoDisponivelException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
            return Mono.just(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Getter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class ConsultaCNDServiceImpl implements ConsultaCNDService {

    @Value("${serpro.acesso.token}")
    private String token;

    private WebClientService webClientService;
    private CertidaoCNDService certidaoCNDService;
    
    @Autowired
    public ConsultaCNDServiceImpl(WebClientService webClientService, CertidaoCNDService certidaoCNDService) {
        this.webClientService = webClientService;
        this.certidaoCNDService = certidaoCNDService;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Mono<String> consultarServicoCNDStatus() {
        return Mono.just("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA"); //webClientService.getRequest(SerproRoutes.CNDRoutes.STATUS_ROUTE, token);
    }

    @Override
    public CertidaoCNDResponse consultarCertidaoCND(ConsultaCertidaoCNDRequest request) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

WebClient

```
@Override
public Mono<String> getRequest(String url, String token) {
    RequestHeadersSpec<?> responseSpec = client.get().uri(url).header("Authorization", token);
    
    Mono<String> serviceResponse = responseSpec.exchangeToMono(r -> {
        if (r.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
            return r.bodyToMono(String.class);
        } else {
            return r.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
        }
    });
    
    return serviceResponse;
}
```

Note that there is no reference to anything JPA in these, but we use JPA and Hibernate for persistency. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: JPA and Hibernate is not supported by `webflux` unless you are using the reactive/hibernate library which is still in beta i believe. None of the code you have posted has anything to do with error you have posted. Please produce a smol reproducible example that is runnable, as you said, there is no JPA related code here, so this is not where the error lies.

Comment: Is it still unresolved? Do you have an interceptor declared in your project?